# How can Digimon come into real world?

Tags: digimon

As we know, Digimons are digital monsters made of Data in the Computer.
So in Digimon Adventure 01 and 02, all the Digimons come to the real world for a mission. But if they are just a piece of data, then how can they actually come out of the computer and take form?
Data needs a medium to compile and take form and the real world does not provide that medium, it only happens in devices that understand the data.

Comment: lol it is a premonition of what the future holds

Comment: Data in the *Digimon* universe is not the same as data in the real world. It's revealed (for sure in DA02, I don't remember where else) that Digimon actually have souls, and this is a result of the Digital World and the real world actually be directly connected. I'll try to get a more solid and complete answer when I have time, if no one else has by then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I remember in Digimon Adventure 2 there being a gate between the Digital World and the Real World which has a "corridor" where anything is possible.

BlackWarGreymon sacrificed himself to protect the Gate which when Mytoismon tried to break though it from the Real World ended up getting trapped in this corridor because of the seal BlackWarGreymon made, this is were we see the Digidestined able to have their partners assume every evolution form at the same time, as the battle continued Mytoismon was pushed back into the Digital World and the multiple forms disappear when they enter the Digital World probably because of Data Limits in the Digital World.

I would assume all travel between the 2 worlds is done though this Gate and "corridor" where the "corridor" is used to make digimon real and turn people into data and some objects into digimon (as seen in Frontier with the trains), the Gate itself probably doesn't have a fixed point.

Comment: Hmm.. this isn't so solid. But i think it pretty much gives an idea of what actually is happening! 
Thanks though :)

Answer (score 5):

It is explained in Digimon Tamers:

When a digimon materializes in the real world, it creates protein and other components from the air and nearby matter (exactly how, if it involves nuclear fusion or not, is unclear) to create a body using energy and data from the digital world.

The same is true when humans travel to the digital world. Their bodies are converted to digital "energy" and this energy is recombined into real bodies. As seen in s2, the clothing can be changed by the mindset of the children.

There is some effort to cross to and from, so usually digimon and children only use gates, places where the boundaries are thinner. Only special digimon like Grani can freely move to and from the digial world.

Answer (score 2):

Well there is no telling for sure how they can because in Digimon Adventures or Digital Monsters season 2, there is a gate to enter into the digital world and back. And in Digimon Tamers, the Digimon monster that you see Growlmon fight with comes through a vortex somehow, so they probably have many ways. But we will never know for sure if Digimon are real so we do not know if they can come or not.